# Glitches in Premiere exports

Tags: premiere, macbook

When I'm using intensive plugins like Film Convert, and some Red Giant plugins that use the GPU, I get glitches appearing in my exported videos.

If I delete the render files and switch to software render only, there are fewer glitches, but still occasionally some.

Does anyone else experience this?
Why does it happen?
Has my laptop's GPU gone bad? (If so, how can I confirm this?)

It appears to have got worse recently, but it's hard to tell...

[image]

Comment: Very strange. I don't think it's a GPU problem, because it still occurs with software render. The rendering is done with multiple threads in both cases, i.e it is done in parallel. The GPU reaches way higher level of parallelism. So I think the problem is caused by a bug related to parallelism, which would fit the observation that the effect is stronger with GPU.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this post](https://community.adobe.com/t5/premiere-pro/glitch-on-export/m-p/11136155?page=1), it might be because I'm using iPhone video footage which for some reason is rated at 30.01fps.  They recommend converting it to 30fps first using Handbrake. I haven't tried this yet, so not sure whether it will fix it.

Comment: I had a similar problem with footage from iphone. A quick conversion to a framerate that makes more sense then 30.01 fps (what the hell?!) did the trick for me.